# Regex + Python to remove specific trailing and ending characters from value in tab delimited file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

It's been years (and years) since I've done any regex, so turning to experts on here since it's likely a trivial exercise :)

I have a tab delimited file and on each line I have a certain fields that have values such as:

- foo
- bar
- b"foo's bar"
- b'bar foo'
- b'carbar'

(A complete line in the file might be something like:

123\t **b'bar foo'** \tabc\t123\r\n

I want to get rid of all the leading b', b" and trailing ", ' from that field on every line.  So given the example line above, after running the regex, I'd get:

123\t **bar foo** \tabc\t123\r\n

Bonus points if you can give me the python blurb to run this over the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each line you can use

```
re.sub(r'''(?<![^\t\n])\W*b(["'])(.*)\1\W*(?![^\t\n])''', r'\2', line)
```

and for bonus points:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''(?<![^\t\n])\W*b(["'])(.*?)\1\W*?(?![^\t\n])''')
with open('outfile', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in open('infile'):
        outfile.write(pattern.sub(r'\2', line))
```

Answer (score 1):

(^|\t)b[\"']
should match the leadings, and for the trailing:

\"'
should do it

In Python, you do:

```
import re
r1 = re.compile("(^|\t)b[\"']")
r2 = re.compile("[\"'](\t|$)")
```

then just use

```
r1.sub("\\1", yourString)
r2.sub("\\1", yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "b\"foo's bar\"".replace('b"',"").replace("b'","").rstrip("\"'")
"foo's bar"
>>> "b'bar foo'".replace('b"',"").replace("b'","").rstrip("\"'")
'bar foo'
>>>
```